# Confusion about Heun's method for integration (or differentiation).

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, maxima-software

*Short version:* I am trying to implement a time response for analog transfer functions, based on Heun's method, to be implemented in C++, but I can't.

---

*Long version* (this may get long, so if you don't have the patience, skip this question):

Consider this test transfer function (TF):

$$H(s)=\frac{Y(s)}{X(s)}=\frac{a_2s^2+a_1s+a_0}{b_2s^2+b_1 s+b_0}=\frac{2.3s^2+0.1s+4.5}{1.3s^2+0.7s+1.1}$$

where the input, X(s), can be any signal, Dirac, Heaviside, sine, noise, etc, but *sampled*, because I need this to be implemented in C++; thus, it's a vector. In order to make a time reponse formula out of it, and to avoid derivatives, I had integrated the TF to give:

$$y(t)=a_2x(t)+\omega\int{\left[a_1x(t)-b_1 x(t)+\omega\int{\left(a_0 x(t)-b_0 y(t)\right)\text{d}t}\right]\text{d}t}$$

This was used to implement it with the basic forward Euler (T=sampling period, and from now on consider all $a_n$ and $b_n$ terms as scaled by $1/b_2$):

$$\begin{align}y''_{n}&=T\left(a_0 x_{n-2} - b_0 y_{n-2}\right) + y''_{n-1}\\
y'_{n}&=T\left(a_1 x_{n-1} - b_1 y_{n-1} + y''_{n}\right) + y'_{n-1}\\
y_n&=a_2 x_n + y'_{n}\end{align}$$

where the initial two samples were given by $y_0=a_2$ and $y_1=T(a_1x_0-b_1y_0)$. While it works, it suffers from the typical cumulative error of forward Euler, meaning I need a sampling time of at least 0.01 (relative to cutoff frequency) in order to have a fairly good accuracy. This also meant the resulting vector (in C++) was large for plotting.

After some searching, I found out about other methods, among them Heun's (HM), so I tried to convert what I had. The problems are as follows:

Since all I read about the method implied it being used as a means to solve ODEs, I gave up the integration in favour of the direct ODE that results from the TF. I tried solving it in terms of a generic input x(t), which, at its worst, is a Dirac function. This means that I would have this:

$$b_2y''(t)+b_1y'(t)+b_0y(t)=a_2\delta''(t)+a_1\delta'(t)+a_0\delta(t)$$

so two derivatives of Dirac. User @LutzL made it clear that I need that the right hand side be at least as smooth a function as the left side, for which he was kind enough to [provide a solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2834498/334505), because I realized I need to calculate the initial conditions in order to go further.

But this means a continuous function, which I don't have, since the input is a vector. What's more, all the descriptions so far give solutions for continuous time ODEs, or some function to be approximated, which I don't have. But if I did, this is what I would have come up with:

$$z=y'\Rightarrow$$
$$b_2z'=a_2x''+a_1x'+a_0x-b_1z-b_0y$$

But what do I do with $x''$ and $x'$? Maybe transform them as (i.e.) $x'=w$, in order to keep the ODE as a 1st order, but then what do I do with $w$? Do I use it in the formula of $z=y'-x'$? Do I leave it in the formula for $z'$? If I follow the linked answer from @LutzL, I get the analog, continuous time function, which I don't have because the input is some unknown series of discrete samples.

Also, if I am to try to determine whether the input is steep, and, thus, risking discontinuity, how would I do that with discrete values? Because I approximate the Dirac (or Kronecker delta) by having the first sample as 1/T (so the area is 1). What's stopping me from having a cosine input? If it's low frequency, it will seem as a Heaviside function; if it's conveniently sampled at twice its frequency, I have a train of alternating signs Kronecker deltas; and even if I have a nice sine input, what if the amplitude of it is high enough that sin(T)=1/T? Will that count as discontinuity?

And yet, there has to be a way this is done since they work just fine in SPICE solvers, for example (I couldn't find examples of these). So I thought I'd give up ODEs in favour of, again, integration, which seemed to work before, but needed only adaptation to HM. I won't post everything I have tried, there was a lot of hammering in the process (lacking math skills provides you with a strong arm), but here's the last try, in wxMaxima code. I kept the first two samples as in forward Euler, since they seem quite close (<1%) to what LTspice shows (which I know and trust since I've been working with it for many years):

```
y[1] : A2*u[1],
z    : A1*u[1] - B1*y[1],
ky1  : z*t,
kz1  : z + ky1,
ky2  : ky1*(1 + t),
kz2  : kz1*(1 + t),
y[2] : A2*u[2] + (ky1 + ky2)/2,
z    : z + (kz1 + kz2)/2,
```

`u` is the input, `ky` and `kz` are the states and the estimated states. `t` is the sampling period. At this point, another confusion: the formula shows *derivatives*, that is it should be:

$$y'=a_2x'+a_1x-b_1y$$

but isn't $x'$ simply the current sample (which is known, true)? At any rate, other examples seem to treat it this way, so that's what I'll do, too. Next there's a loop:

```
ky1  : z,
kz1  : (A1*u[i-1] - B1*y[i-1] + (A0*u[i-2] - B0*y[i-2])*t)*t,
ky2  : ky1*(1 + t),
kz2  : (A1*u[i] - B1*y[i-1] + (A0*u[i-1] - B0*y[i-1])*t + kz1)*t,
y[i] : A2*u[i] + (ky1 + ky2)/2,
z    : z + (kz1 + kz2)/2
```

The biggest problem is that I don't know how to transform the functions (i.e. $f_1(t,z,y)$) shown in all the examples into what I have, samples. Whatever came out was by ogling to the forward Euler. Whatever I tried, the results are either diverging (as if the poles on the right hand side), or come as ultra damped. But if I try with a sine input, it seems to converge to ..some sort of response, wrong, but it converges. Is this because the right side isn't smooth if it's a step, or impulse? At this point I simply don't understand how to do it and am confused a lot, and I would rather have someone provide the understanding for it, as opposed as simply replicating some steps like a robot.

---

How do I make the Heun's method work in code that works with a vector of samples as input? What do I use as the functions that are used in the examples for ODE of continuous time examples? But, mostly, why? It doesn't matter whether it turns out that the equations are based on the derivative, or on the integration method, as long as I understand it and it works.

Comment: The Euler step for $y''(t)+b_1y'(t)+b_0y(t)=a_0x(t)$ is \begin{align}y'_n&=y'_{n-1}+h(a_0x_{n-1}-b_0y_{n-1}-b_1y'_{n-1}),\\y_n&=y_{n-1}+hy'_{n-1}.\end{align} Or if you define $v=y'+b_1y$ then $v'=a_0x-b_0y$ so that then the Euler method reads \begin{align}v_n&=v_{n-1}+h(a_0x_{n-1}-b_0y_{n-1}),\\y_n&=y_{n-1}+h(v_{n-1}-b_1y_{n-1}.\end{align} Both variants have elements of your first formulas, but are in other aspects rather different. Please provide more background on what your initial problem is and what kind of solution you are expecting in the end.

Comment: @LutzL Thank you for the comment. What I have is the basic forward Euler with which I calculate the time response, but it takes a very low sampling period to be reasonable. How can I transform what I have into Heun's method, which is much more precise? I dug up some answers here, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/439458/334505), for example, but in the 2nd bullet, where did a and $\alpha$ come from, what's their purpose (they don't seem to be anywhere else in there)? All I know is that Heun's implies an approximation for the next step, and, based on the link above, I think (cont'd)

Comment: ...I now understand that, indeed, I have to use the same equations for the next step, which explains why it said that Heun's is based on an implicit method, and that requires more computation. I'm currently trying to concoct up the formulas. Still, it's a 2nd order, so a bit more complicated, but I found out [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/477123/334505) which transforms it into two 1st order, it should be easier. I think I also have to not integrate the equation for the time response, instead, keep it as derivatives, which is closer to what I see in all the examples.

Comment: Yes, most numerical methods are developed for first order systems, thus you need to translate your higher order ODE into a first order system. That is also the basis of the two variants I gave, either using $v=y'$ or $v=y'+b_1y$. From your notation you might want to base your solver not on the one-step Heun method, but on some linear multi-step method like the implicit trapezoidal method or any higher order method.

Comment: @LutzL I hope you'll forgive me for being a bit of a pest, but it seems that my attempts so far also lacked a proper initial condition setup. I seem to be making progress (the first two points are calculated well, the rest go off), but, given [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2834498/334505), is it possible that I could properly determine if the input is a Dirac, or step, so that I can properly calculate the initial conditions? Or does the fact that this is a numerical method simply imply that the derivative of Dirac is simply `x[n-1]` (and similar for Heaviside)?

Comment: For numerical methods you need that the right side is smooth, at least of the same differentiability order as the order of the method. By restarting at the location of a discontinuity you can also handle right sides that are piecewise smooth. There is no direct way to handle distributions numerically. It might be possible to get the solution as a linear combination of fixed distributions with smooth coefficients and to solve the equations for the coefficients numerically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a sampled input signal $x$, so that you either need to interpolate it to apply general Runge-Kutta methods that use values inside the interval, or apply multi-step methods that only use samples at the given sample points. Heun's method can be interpreted as predictor-corrector implementation of the implicit trapezoidal method
$$
\vec u_{n+1}-\vec u_n=\frac{h}2(f(t_n,\vec u_n)+f(t_{n+1},\vec u_{n+1})),
$$
so that it fits into both frameworks.

The next point is the derivatives on the right side. You could use divided differences, but that will amplify the error. The other variant is to compensate for the derivatives of $x$ in
$$
b_2y''+b_1y'+b_0y=a_2x''+a_1x'+a_0x
$$
by explicitly incorporating terms based on anti-derivatives of $x$ in a parametrization of the solution, as integration is usually more robust than differentiation.
$$
y = u + c_2x+c_1X+c_0\Xi,~~\text{ where }~~ \Xi'=X,~X'=x
$$
from where you get
$$
y'=u' + c_2x'+c_1x+c_0X\\
y''=u'' + c_2x''+c_1x'+c_0x
$$
so that in the differential equation
$$
b_2u''+b_1u'+b_0u=a_2x''+a_1x'+a_0x-b_2c_2x''-(b_2c_1+b_1c_2)x'-(b_2c_0+b_1c_1+b_0c_2)x-(b_1c_0+b_0c_1)X-b_0c_0\Xi
$$
the derivative terms are removed by setting $b_2c_2=a_2$, $b_2c_1+b_1c_2=a_1$, $b_2c_0+b_1c_1+b_0c_2=a_0$ and thus obtaining the first-order system
\begin{align}
X'&=x\\
\Xi'&=X\\
u'&=v\\
v'&=-\frac1{b_2}\left(b_1v+b_0u+(b_1c_0+b_0c_1)X+b_0c_0\Xi\right)
\end{align}
Now apply the Heun method or the implicit trapezoidal method (as the system is linear, this can be solved directly) and then reconstruct $y$ from $u$.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T=25;
N = 500;
t=np.linspace(0,T,N+1);
h = t[1]-t[0];
t=t-h;
x = np.zeros(N+1);
x[1]=1/h;  # delta pulse, triangular with base 2h and height 1/h

Xi = np.zeros(N+1);
X  = np.zeros(N+1);
u = np.zeros(N+1);
v = np.zeros(N+1);

a2,a1,a0,b2,b1,b0=2.3, 0.1, 4.5, 1.3, 0.7, 1.1
#y[n] = u[n] + c2*x[n] + c1*X[n] + c0*Xi[n]
c2 = a2/b2
c1 = (a1-c2*b1)/b2 # c1*b2+c2*b1 = a1
c0 = (a0 - c1*b1 - c2*b0)/b2 # c0*b2+c1*b1+c2*b0 = a0
d1 = b1*c0+b0*c1;
d0 = b0*c0;
for i in range(N):
    X[i+1] = X[i] + 0.5*h*(x[i]+x[i+1]);
    Xi[i+1] = Xi[i] + 0.5*h*(X[i]+X[i+1]);
    # u' = v; v' = -(b1*v+b0*u+d1*X+d0*Xi)/b2
    k1u = v[i]
    k1v = -(b1*v[i]+b0*u[i]+d1*X[i]+d0*Xi[i])/b2
    k2u = v[i]+h*k1v
    k2v = -(b1*(v[i]+h*k1v)+b0*(u[i]+h*k1u)+d1*X[i+1]+d0*Xi[i+1])/b2
    u[i+1] = u[i] + 0.5*h*(k1u+k2u)
    v[i+1] = v[i] + 0.5*h*(k1v+k2v)

z = (-b1+(b1**2+0j-4*b0*b2)**0.5)/(2*b2)
a, b = z.real, z.imag
y0, y1 = c1, c0
m = (y1-a*y0)/b;# y1=y'(0)=a*y0+m*b 
y = np.exp(a*t)*(y0*np.cos(b*t)+m*np.sin(b*t)) 
plt.plot(t,u+c2*x+c1*X+c0*Xi,'-b', lw=4); plt.plot(t,y,'-y',lw=1.5);
plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you *very much* for putting up with a dense antimathematician. I realize that, while I *did* follow your other answer, I only made it for the right side, and I left it as it is, in a childish way. I gave up when I saw bad results, ashamed of asking what's wrong after getting two answers (not one). I should've continued, it was going well, but unfinished. A question: I see you made x with its 2nd sample as non-zero. Is that a must? Because I changed it by adding a few lines before the loop, dealing with X[1], Xi[1], ... , for the case the signal starts directly. I'd vote twice if I could.

Comment: One thing I notice: the results are *very* close with the bilinear transform. Here's the first 5 samples for 0.1 step, BLT: `[17.315,-0.63725,-0.40465,-0.1809,0.032638]`, and Heun: `[17.314,-0.63705,-0.40409,-0.18005,0.033695]`. By comparison, forward Euler: `[17.692,-0.87574,-0.63213,-0.39424,-0.1638]`, and LTspice: `-0.874522, -0.63409, -0.401042, -0.176909` (without the t=0, since the input is modeled with a 1kV over 1ms). It seemed strange that they should come closer to F.E., but then I measured with 0.1s delay, in LTspice, and they are very close. I'll try the variable step Heun, too.

Comment: I just now realize I missed on my main point, and that is that you made me see *why* I was wrong, and how I can correct it. Thank you for the lesson. Sorry for the verbosity.

Comment: I put the pulse in the second position to have the full delta pulse. In principle position 1 is time 0, and when shifting the exact solution by $h$, as you observed, the error is even smaller. The solution should be left-padded with zeros for the amount of memory used in the method, for Heun that is 1 place, for a 3-tap third order multi-step method this would be two places etc.

Comment: Yes, we must obey causality, that shows in the code from the question: the first lines before the loop take care of those initial conditions for what would have been time t=-1 (and t=-2, if needed). Forward Euler and bilinear transform also use initial conditions like that. For my part, in a rather phiosophical way, I feel the filter should be the one accomodating, since the signal can come any time, while the filter existed before the signal. In your code, you shift the pulse time relative to the filter. Works any way. I think this falls under the "de gustibus non disputandum" category. :-)

Comment: It is the problem with arrays with a definitive start at 0 or 1. I implemented the shift in the time axis and modified the graphics to still show both curves, the exact solution in yellow is now almost exactly centered in the broad strokes of the numerical solution.