# Solving differential equations using summation of singularity functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, signal-processing

[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osvPL.png)

I'm stuck at Problem 2.56 of Alan Oppenheim's Signals and Systems book. What is the method called? Where or which book can I learn more about it? It assumes $y(t)=\displaystyle \sum_l \alpha_l u_l(t)$. I didn't learn it while studying basic differential equations.

Extra notes:

$u_o(t)=\delta(t)$

$u_1(t)=\frac{d \delta(t)}{dt}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: A similar question was discussed in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2834640/115115, perhaps you can find inspiration there.